# Insert set variable row based on cell values matching in two ranges

Tags: excel, loops, foreach, vba

So I have been working on some code that identifies unique values between two ranges. I then want a selected row copied and inserted where it's relatively located in range 2. (Please see the code below where it reads ****Need help here)

I want the non-unique value, located right below the unique value, to be found in range one and a row inserted right above it.

Also, I plan to use this code between two workbooks. Range 1 and Range two will be in different workbooks of the same instance.

```
Option Explicit
Public WorkRng1 As Range
Public WorkRng2 As Range
Public WorkRng3 As Range
Public Rng1 As Range
Public Rng2 As Range
Public Rng3 As Range
Public blkRow As Range

Public Sub SetRanges()

Dim xTitleId As String
xTitleId = "Compare Ranges"
Set WorkRng1 = Application.InputBox("Please Select TASK ID Range in **INVOICE REVIEW FILE**", xTitleId, Type:=8)
Set WorkRng2 = Application.InputBox("Please Select TASK ID Range in **BUDGET GRID**", xTitleId, Type:=8)
Set WorkRng3 = Application.InputBox("Please Select **UNIT COST** Range in Budget Grid", xTitleId, Type:=8)

Call CompareRanges
'Error Handler
Whoa:
        Select Case Err.Number
            Case 1004
                MsgBox "Check Your Column Letters!", vbInformation, "Oops!"
            Case 424
                Exit Sub
        End Select
End Sub


Public Sub CompareRanges()
Dim blkRow As Range

'clears color format
WorkRng2.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
'finds duplicate values
For Each Rng1 In WorkRng1
    For Each Rng2 In WorkRng2
        If Rng1.Value = Rng2.Value Then
            Rng2.Interior.Color = VBA.RGB(254, 255, 255)
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
Next
'find unique values and highlights red
For Each Rng2 In WorkRng2
    For Each Rng3 In WorkRng3
        If Rng2.Value > 0 And Cells(Rng2.Row, Rng3.Column) <> 0 And Rng2.Interior.Color <> VBA.RGB(254, 255, 255) Then
            Rng2.Interior.Color = VBA.RGB(255, 0, 0)
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
Next
'promts to select blank row to copy
    Set blkRow = Application.InputBox("Enter Row # of 'BLANK' with formulas", "BLANK ROW SELECTION", Type:=8)
    blkRow.Copy
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
**'****NEED HELP HERE**
'finds unit id below unique value in range 1 and inserts blank row
For Each Rng1 In WorkRng1
    For Each Rng2 In WorkRng2
        If Rng2.Interior.Color = VBA.RGB(255, 0, 0) And Rng2.Value > 0 Then
            If Rng1.Value = Rng2.Offset(1, 0).Value Then
                blkRow.Copy
                Rng1.EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlDown
                    Application.CutCopyMode = False
            Exit For
            End If
        End If
    Next
Next
'Error Handler
Whoa:
        Select Case Err.Number
            Case 1004
                MsgBox "Check Your Column Letters!", vbInformation, "Oops!"
            Case 424
                Exit Sub
        End Select
End Sub
```

Comment: You never do anything with the copied `blkRow`. Why are you copying it?

Comment: @BruceWayne that is the row I would like inserted. it will have formulas in various positions in it. I realized there was an extra line in there. I'll edit it out

Comment: right now when I run the code it is continuously inserting the `blkRow` as the end of the selection i made with the input box when i select the range for `Rng1`